# Measuring the randomness of texts

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, it.information-theory, combinatorics-on-words, computational-linguistics

The question concerns statistic properties of random words in a finite alphabet $A$.

By $A^{<\omega}$ we denote the set of all words in the alphabet $A$, i.e. finite sequences of elements of $A$.

Let $w$ be a word in the alphabet $A$. A nonempty word $u\in A^{<\omega}$ is called *$w$-fixed* if $w$ contains a unique subword, equal to $u$.

The *dictionary* of the word $w$ is defined as the set $D(w)$ of all minimal $w$-fixed subwords of $w$.

The fraction $$\rho(w)=\frac{|D(w)|}{|w|}$$will be called the *randomness* of the text $w$. Here $|D(w)|$ and $|w|$ is the cardinality of the set $D(w)$ and the length of the word $w$, respectively.

For example, for the word "Mathoverflow" its dictionary is the set $\{$'M', 'A', 'T', 'H', 'V', 'E', 'R', 'F', 'L', 'W'$\}$ and the randomness is equal to
$$\frac{10}{12}\approx 0.833...$$

On the other hand, for the word "Stackexchange" the distionary is the set $\{$'S', 'T', 'K', 'X', 'H',  'N', 'G', 'AC'$\}$ and its randomness is equal to
$$\frac{8}{13}\approx 0.615...$$

The computer calculations show that the randomness of the text about Mathoverflow in Wikipedia has length 2570 and randomness equal to $\frac{1087}{2570}=0.423...$

The text about Conan Doyl from Wikipedia has randomness $\frac{10120}{25710}\approx 0.394...$

and the text about Communism in Wikipedia has randomness $\frac{11952}{40230}\approx 0.297...$

Three randomly generated texts of the same length as the mentioned meaningfull texts from Wikipedia have randomness $\frac{2220}{2570}=0.864...$, $\frac{19866}{25710}=0.773...,$ and $\frac{33552}{40230}=0.834...$, respectively (if my program counts well).

So, we see that real meaningfull texts have smaller randomness (which decreases with growth of the length of the text) comparing to the randomness of random texts.

> **Problem 1.** What is an expected value $\rho_n(|A|)$ of the randomness $\rho(w)$ of a random word of a fixed length $n$ in the alphabet $A$? What is the value of the limit $\rho_\infty(|A|)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\rho_n(|A|)$? (I hope that this limit does exist and depend on $|A|$).

> **Problem 2.** Is the above randomness of texts related to other randomness measures like entropy?

**Remark.** Taking into account that any two minimal $w$-fixed words with the same starting letter coincide, we can conclude that $|D(w)|\le|w|$ and hence $\rho_n(|A|)\le 1$ for any alphabet $A$ and any $n$. Consequently, $\rho_\infty(|A|)\le 1$ (if this limit exists).

Comment: I think that there is a typo in the definition of $w$-fixed word $u$. You write  that $u$ is $w$-fixed if  (the alphabet) $A$ contains a unique subword  equal to $u$.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu You are right. The misprint is corrected. Thank you.

Comment: Why is the denominator of the first large example 2570 and not 2579?  Also, did you try randomly permuting the words of the text (keeping the words themselves intact)?

Comment: How did you generate random words in your simulation? I mean what is the distribution on $A^n$ from which they are sampled? Also, which distribution do you mean when talking about random words in Problem 1? If it is uniform, then there is no surprise as it is known since Morse and Markov (let alone Shannon) that the empirical distributions of real texts are very far from uniform.

Comment: @RW I generate random texts in Pythen using the built-in generator of pseudo-random numbers. Asking about the expected value, I have in mind the uniform distribution (all letters from the alphabet $A$ appear with the same probability).

Comment: So you sampled letters independently from the uniform distribution on $A$, which leads to the uniform distribution on $A^n$ - right? Then - as I said above - your random texts are very far from real life ones. I think that one should add one more variable to your question (a shift invariant measure on infinite words in the alphabet $A$) and ask about the averages with respect to the $n$-dimensional distributions of this measure. Moreover, in this setup one can also ask about the existence of a limit along almost every infinite word.

Comment: Not addressing the question as is, rather proposing a method of detection of meaningfulness of a text, that also addresses the objection by @BrendanMcKay. The keywords are LNRE (large number of rare events) and Zipf-Mandelbrot law. In its strongest form the principle is that in a *meaningful* and *whole* text, for small $n$ (like $n<10$) the proportion of *words* that appear exactly $n$ times is about $\frac1{n(n+1)}$ of words that appear (at least once). In a random text, this fails, as well as in a chunk of a whole text or a union of several diverse whole texts.

Comment: @RW I perfectly understand that my random texts are very far from the real texts. My quiestion was exactly about the mean value of the dictionary for a random text (random in my "uniform" understanding) and why it is close to 0,8... in computer experiments? What is special about 0.8...? Maybe it should be 1 at infinity?

Comment: Sorry - I was mislead by the way you opposed "real meaningful texts" to "random texts", whereas in my opinion the point is the difference between different ways in which a text can exhibit randomness. Anyway, I definitely agree that this is a meaningful, interesting, and open question. One can also ask the same question about the sum of the lengths of the minimal fixed subwords (is it clear that the corresponding ratio never exceeds 1? by the way, how do see that $|D(w)|\le |w|$? - there must be a trivial reason for that).

Comment: @RW Yes, I see why $|D(w)|\le|w|$. Just observe that two minimal words with the same starting letter coincide.